# Does someone know psinprot.sys?

Tags: virus

The PC of my friend crashes and the message report that the problem is in psinprot.sys file.
I search on web but I find this page (and not as first result):

http://wiki.cloudantivirus.com/index.php/Known_Issues

and many results that spoke about this file as a malware and suggest an removal tool... The problem is that I don't know nothing about these websites... Here are a list:
- freefixer.com;
- novirus365.net
- prevx.com

Some one know that file or one of the site that I mentioned and can tell me where is the truth?
Another information is that he installed Panda Antivirus Free (I don't know if the Cloud version or the "standard") and now it doesn't work properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the sites listed - or any I can find, list psinprot.sys in relation to malware.

The most likely scenario is Panda Anti-Virus has gotten messed up somehow, and so should be reinstalled.

Comment: @ Paul : yes the problem was the antivirus... when I told him to close the processes from task manager the PC didn't crash anymore! Thank you for your answer!